# Expected number of button clicks

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

Suppose we have $N$ buttons and each button can be clicked with probability $p_i$. The game stops when the player clicks the button with $i = 1$. Once a button is clicked, the player can not click the same button again. What is the expected number of clicks?

I am not able to answer this question for $ N > 2 $

For $N = 1$, $E[x] = 1$

For $N = 2$, suppose $p_1 = 5 / 6$ and $p_2 = 1 / 6$ , then $ E[x] = 1*p_1 + 2 * p_2 = 1.167$

Can anyone please help me to solve for any $N$?

Comment: Treat $p_1$ as the successful probability, then $N$ follows geometric distribution.

Comment: If you can solve $N=2$, then @peterwhy 's suggestion amounts to lumping all the buttons together for $i \gt 1$, thus reducing to the case where there are only two buttons.  First button still has $p_1$ chance of being clicked with each "Bernoulli trial", and the fictitious second button has a complementary chance of being clicked.

Comment: @peterwhy Sorry, not $N$ follows geometric distribution, but $x$ follows geometric distribution.

Comment: @peterwhy Can u elaborate in the answer? Probability can be different for each button. I don't get it how it will be Geometric Distribution.

Comment: @AnishShah all buttons other than the first behave in the same way: they add $1$ to the count of clicks, and they don't stop the game. That's why hardmath suggested you to consider them as a single button.

Comment: E[X] = 1*p1 + 2*p2 is incorrect for the example you have given. For any particular $p_i, E(X) = 1/p_i$

Comment: For the particular example of yours, if you have still not got it, E[x] = $1*5/6 + 2*1/6*5/6 + 3*(1/6)^2*5/6 + 4*(1/6)^3*5/6 + ....$ = 6/5. See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%285%2F6%29*sum+%28n%2B1%29*%281%2F6%29^n%2C+n+%3D+0+to+oo

Comment: It seems the OP has in mind the setting where, once a button is clicked, one never clicks it again. That this kind of "detail" is still unclear after 7 comments and 1 answer, strongly suggests the question should be closed until improvement.

Comment: @Did sorry. updated the question. I was offline.

Comment: @trueblueanil E[X] = 1*p1 + 2*p2 is correct ...

Comment: You gave a wrong question which you have updated some minutes back, and go on down voting the right answer to the question you originally posed a day back !

Comment: Does anyone want to try a Markov chain argument? Does that apply here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the number of buttons be $N$.

And probabilities of buttons are $p_1, p_2, p_3 ... p_n.$

The expected value $E[X] = N - \frac{p_1}{p_1 + p_2} - \frac{p_1}{p_1 + p_3} - \frac{p_1}{p_1 + p_4} .... \frac{p_1}{p_1 + p_n}$

Will update the full derivation in sometime.

**UPDATE:**

Consider $N = 3$

$E[X] = 1*p_1 + 2*(p_2*\frac{p_1}{p_1 + p_3} + p_3*\frac{p_1}{p_1 + p_2}) + 3*(p_2*\frac{p_3}{p_3 + p_1}*1 + p_3*\frac{p_2}{p_2 + p_1}*1)$

$E[X] = p_1 + 2*p_2*\frac{p_1}{p_1 + p_3} + 2*p_3*\frac{p_1}{p_1 + p_2} + 3*p_2*\frac{p_3}{p_1 + p_3} + 3*p_3*\frac{p_2}{p_1 + p_2}$

Rearranging terms with same denominator...

$E[X] = p_1 + ( 2*\frac{p_2*p_1}{p_1 + p_3} + 3*\frac{p_2*p_3}{p_1 + p_3}) + (2*\frac{p_3*p_1}{p_1 + p_2}  + 3*\frac{p_3*p_2}{p_1 + p_2})$

$E[X] = p_1 + ( 3*p_2 - \frac{p_1*p_2}{p_1 + p_3}) + (3*p_3 - \frac{p_1 * p_3}{p_1 + p_2})$

$E[X] = 3 (p_1 + p_2 + p_3) - (2*p_1  + \frac{p_1*p_2}{p_1 + p_3} + \frac{p_1 * p_3}{p_1 + p_2})$

Since, Sum of all probabilities is 1

$E[X] = 3 - p_1*(2*  + \frac{p_2}{p_1 + p_3} + \frac{p_3}{p_1 + p_2})$

$E[X] = 3 - p_1*(\frac{2*(p_1 + p_2)*(p_1 + p_3) + p_2*(p_1 + p_2) + p_3*(p_1 + p_3)}{(p_1 + p_2)*(p_1 + p_3)})$

$E[X] = 3 - p_1*(\frac{(p_1 + p_2)*(p_1 + p_3) + (p_1 + p_2)*(p_1 + p_3) + p_2*(p_1 + p_2) + p_3*(p_1 + p_3)}{(p_1 + p_2)*(p_1 + p_3)})$

$E[X] = 3 - p_1*(\frac{(p_1 + p_2)*(p_1 + p_2 + p_3) + (p_1 + p_3)*(p_1 + p_2 + p_3)}{(p_1 + p_2)*(p_1 + p_3)})$

$E[X] = 3 - p_1*(\frac{(p_1 + p_2) + (p_1 + p_3)}{(p_1 + p_2)*(p_1 + p_3)})$

$E[X] = 3 - p_1*(\frac{1}{p_1 + p_3} + \frac{1}{p_1 + p_2})$

$E[X] = 3 - (\frac{p_1}{p_1 + p_2} + \frac{p_1}{p_1 + p_3})$

$E[X] = 1 + \frac{p_2}{p_1 + p_2} + \frac{p_3}{p_1 + p_3}$

If you do the same thing for N = 4 and onwards.. you get the same thing.. but it is messy...

Comment: If the button distribution is uniform, we get $E=(1+N)/2$

Comment: I'd like to see your derivation

Comment: @UriGoren I have updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: @AnishShah I have checked your answe for $N=3$. It is correct (provided $p_1>0$).

Answer (score 3):

Let's try to look at this problem recursively:

If we have only one button, the expected number of clicks is obviously 1
$$E_1=1$$

For any $n$, the expected number of clicks is:
$$E_n=p_1+(1-p_1)(n-1)E_{n-1}$$
Since we have $n-1$ choices to choose a button that isn't button #1, and the probability of that happening is $1-p_1$.

**This should be enough to answer your question**

If you want to have a closed form solution, this can be done by solving the recursive relation.

We'll define a [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function)
$$f(x)=\sum{E_nx^n}$$

$$f(x)=E_0+\sum_{n=1}{(p_1+(1-p_1)(n-1)E_{n-1})x^n}=E_0+\sum_{n=1}{p_1x^n}+(1-p_1)\sum_{n=1}{(n-1)E_{n-1}x^n}=E_0+\frac{p_1x}{1-x}+(1-p_1)x\sum{(n-1)E_{n-1}x^{n-2}}=1+\frac{p_1x}{1-x}+(1-p_1)x^2f'(x)$$

We got a [differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation):
$$f'(x)-\frac{f(x)}{x^2(p_1-1)}=\frac{p_1(x-1)+1}{(1-x)(p_1-1)x^2}$$
This is a linear differential equation, The [solution](http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/first/lineareq/lineareq.html) of this type equation is described [here](http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/first/lineareq/lineareq.html):

Then, in order to get the closed form equation, substitute f here:

$$E_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$$
I haven't done the calculations myself, but I can assure you that the result is not pretty.

Comment: Something is wrong with the recursive formula here:  If you plug in $n=2$, you get $E_2=p_1+(1-p_1)(2-1)E_1=p_1+(1-p_1)(1)(1)=1$, which disagrees with the OP's result (and the formula in my answer, where the answer for two buttons is given as $E_1(a)=1+a$, the index in my formula indicating the number of *non*-terminating buttons).

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer, meant to point the OP in a hopefully helpful direction.

If the non-terminating buttons $i=2$ to $N$ can each be clicked more than once, as the original statement of the problem seemed to allow, then the expected number of clicks is simply $1/p_1$, as true blue anil correctly answered.

When buttons cannot be clicked more than once, the answer will be a function of the probabilities assigned to buttons $2$ to $N$.  As the OP correctly said, the answer is (trivially) $1$ when $N=1$ and $p_1+2p_2$ when $N=2$.

For examining the next case, I think it's convenient to change a bit of notation, letting $a$, $b$, $c$, etc. denote the probabilities of clicking (and thus eliminating) the non-terminating buttons $2$, $3$, $4$, etc., so that $p_1=1-(a+b+c+\cdots)$.  We can express the OP's findings as

$$E_0=1$$
and
$$E_1(a)=1+a$$

where the subscript on $E$ counts the number of *non*-terminating buttons.  If I've done all the algebra correctly, the answer in the next case is

$$E_2(a,b)={1-(a^2-ab+b^2)\over(1-a)(1-b)}$$

Note, in particular, that

$$E_2(a,0)={1-a^2\over1-a}=1+a=E_1(a)$$

which makes sense: if the second non-terminating button has no chance of being clicked, then you really only have one non-terminating button.  Also,

$$E_2({1\over3},{1\over3})={1-1/9\over4/9}=2$$

which accords with the easily proved general result

$$E_{N-1}({1\over N},{1\over N},\ldots,{1\over N})={N+1\over2}$$

So let me summarize what we have so far:

$$\begin{align}
E_0&=1\\
\\
E_1(a)&={1-a^2\over1-a}\\
\\
E_2(a,b)&={1-(a^2+b^2-ab)\over(1-a)(1-b)}\\
\end{align}$$

At first glance, this suggests

$$E_3(a,b,c)={1-(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)\over(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)}$$

which certainly satisfies $E_3(a,b,0)=E_2(a,b)$.  But it *doesn't* satisfy $E_3({1\over4},{1\over4},{1\over4})={5\over2}$, so it can't be correct.  Indeed, I have a feeling the next formula is going to be a somewhat messy one.

Answer (score 0):

Compare it with throwing a die. What is the expected number of throws needed to get a 6 ?

Although there are 6 possible outcomes for each throw, we reduce it to *two*, a 6 with Pr = 1/6, and any other with a Pr = 5/6, and E(X) = 1/p = 6

Similarly, here p = 1/N, and E(X) = N

Comment: Probabilities can be different and not equal every time.

Comment: Ok, suppose there are 4 possible outcomes, $p_1 = 1/3, p_2 = 1/4, p_3 = 1/24, p_4 = 3/8$. Although they are all different probabilities, $p_1= 1/3, \sum_{i=2}^4 p_i = 2/3,$ and  for $p_1, E(X) = \frac{1}{1/3} = 3$

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: Downvote because the answer is wrong.

Comment: @AnishShah You have some nerve... The answer fails to address the problem you now ask because, until a few minutes ago, your question might well have been the one this answer addresses.

Comment: for previous not-updated question also, this answer was wrong. It says that $N$ is the expected number. But, expected number will always be less than $N$ as the game stops when first button is clicked.

Comment: So to get , say, 1 on throws of a die (where N = 6) the expected value has to  be less than 6 throws ? Go back to your books. You are just adding insult to injury !

Answer (score 0):

In order that the game make sense further I shall assume that $p_1>1$.

We can prove the formula $$E[X]=1+\sum_{i=2}^N\frac{p_i}{p_1+p_i}$$ from [your answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1433409/71850) for the general case by induction.

For $N=2$ the formula holds. Assume that $N>2$. Then the induction assumption implies that

$$E[X]=p_1+\sum_{i=2}^N p_i\left(1+1-\frac{p_i}{p_1+p_i}+\sum_{j=2}^N\frac{p_j}{p_1+p_j}\right)=$$

$$p_1+\sum_i p_i\left(1+\frac{p_1}{p_1+p_i}\right)+ \sum_i\sum_j\frac{p_ip_j}{p_1+p_j}=$$

$$p_1+\sum_i p_i\left(1+\frac{p_1}{p_1+p_i}\right)+ \sum_j\sum_i\frac{p_ip_j}{p_1+p_j}=$$

$$p_1+\sum_i p_i\left(1+\frac{p_1}{p_1+p_i}\right)+ \sum_j\frac{(1-p_1)p_j}{p_1+p_j}=$$

$$p_1+\sum_i p_i\left(1+\frac{p_1}{p_1+p_i}+\frac{(1-p_1)}{p_1+p_i}\right)=$$

$$p_1+\sum_i p_i\left(1+\frac{1}{p_1+p_i}\right)=$$

$$1+\sum_i \frac{p_i}{p_1+p_i}.$$